# Not specifying an image to upload gives misleading "format is not supported" error

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, imgur, uploader

I went to upload an image for a question. **I clicked on upload without specifying a file** and it stated:

> "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported."

I find that misleading because no file was specified.

[image: Image File Name Not Specified]

I would rather see `"Please specify a supported image file"`.

Comment: were you trying to upload .gif image ?

Comment: @Lucifer "I clicked on upload without specifying a file"

Comment: What was changed in this last edit? Besides a single '>' in the markdown I see no changes. If this was merely to bump your question, please don't do that. There are other means to get attention for your unanswered question.

Comment: Worth to mention that it's OK when you don't enter URL: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yVCfs.png

Comment: @Bart it says "added 18 characters" so probably he added something then regretted it and removed during the 5 minutes grace period. edmastermind29 you can simply roll back in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

I have added some more checks for image uploads with descriptive messages.