# Wrong error message if I click "upload image" without providing image path

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, imgur

If while editing a post I click onto "Image" button on the toolbar the "Insert an image" form pops up. If I then immediately click "upload" I get this error message:

[image]

Clearly the error message about the unsupported format is irrelevant, the real problem is that I just didn't provide the image path.

Comment: I know this is duplicate. Can't find it right now...

Comment: Hurrayyy I found it: [Not specifying an image to upload gives misleading "format is not supported" error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133659/not-specifying-an-image-to-upload-gives-misleading-format-is-not-supported-err)